# How to get performance report from New Relic to email & slack automatically

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform, newrelic-synthetics

I need to get new relic past 24 hours transaction report for both (Highest error rate & slowest average response time) automatically every day at 5 PM to email & slack.

How can we achieve?

[image]